# Поиск по ассоциативному массиву

Tags: массивы, php, search

Здравствуйте. У меня есть проблема с поиском в ассоциативном массиве.
Вот дамп массива.

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(1)
            ["resource_name"]=>
            string(15) "map-race"
        }
    }
}
```

Мне нужно сделать функцию, которая находила бы по ключу resource_name и возвращала бы значение ключа id. Я в PHP совсем недавно, поэтому не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

К примеру

```
$id = search_map ( "map-race", $aMaps );

if ( $id ) 
{
    echo "found".$id; // 1
}
```

Comment: вам один id надо или несколько ?

[если один](http://us3.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php)

[если несколько](http://us3.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Я решил свою проблему. Спасибо в любом случае.

function search_map ( $sResourceName, $aMaps )
{
 foreach( $aMaps as $key=>$value ) 
 {
  foreach( $aMaps[$key] as $k=>$val ) 
  {
   if ( $aMaps[$key][$k]->resource_name == $sResourceName )
   {
    return $aMaps[$key][$k]->id;
   }
  }
 }

 return NULL;
}